# R: coreNLP - cannot plot getdependency

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I have a short text data:

"I always prefer old-school guy. I have a PhD degree in science. I am really not interested in finding someone with the same background, otherwise life is gonna be boring."

I have used the following codes to get the dependence structure of the text above.

```
dep <- getDependency(anno)
```

but when I tried to plot the sentence structure as suggested in book - Humanities Data in R:

```
plot(anno,3)
```

It should give me the sturcture of the third sentence, but I get is an error message:

```
 Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I am wondering how can this be properly plotted and get a plot like the following.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I've the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have not loaded the plot function for this kind of object.  It appears that the message is coming from the default plot function.